# Switch statement inside getter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I define a `switch` statement inside a getter in Dart?

```dart
// Doesn't work... ❌
get String buttonText => {
  switch (step) {
    case 1: return "Register >";
    case 2: return "Confirmation >";
  }
  throw "Invalid step";
}
```

It fails with what looks like a syntax error:

> Expected to find '}'.dart(expected_token)

I find this weird, because it works just fine in function form:

```dart
// Works fine... ✅
String buttonText() {
  switch (step) {
    case 1: return "Register >";
    case 2: return "Confirmation >";
  }
  throw "Invalid step";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the fat arrow `=>` and it should work fine.

```
String get buttonText {
  ....
```

In dart, you can only have one or the other: Either you have curly brackets, or a fat arrow. In case of curly brackets you must have a return statement. In case of a fat arrow, any expression that comes after it would be the returned value.

```
// either
String get one => "1";

// or
String get one {
  return "1";
}
```

EDIT: (based on [cameron1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9186783/cameron1024)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69672003/switch-statement-inside-getter/69672043#comment123151345_69672043))

The only exception to that rule is if you are returning a map literal, as such: `someFunction() => {}` which is a function that returns an empty set.

Comment: `Unexpected text 'buttonText'. Try removing the text.dart(unexpected_token)`

Comment: Thanks, it's `String get buttonText` 

Comment: "In dart, you can only have one or the other", is basically correct but there is one slight exception: you can have an expression function that returns a map literal, e.g.: `() => {}` is a function that takes no arguments and returns an empty set

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are confusing this with JS/TS (probably?) . As mentioned in the [documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions),

> "Only an expression—not a statement—can appear between the arrow (=>) and the semicolon (;)"

Moreover,

> The => expr syntax is a shorthand for { return expr; }.

Unlike JS, `=> { expr }` is invalid and for multi line statements `{ expr }` should be used instead.

> Note: This rule not only applies to getters, but to functions and setters as well.

Comment: You're actually right. Working on a Typescript backend while building the app in Flutter :)